# App with DeviceActivityReport extension either won't install on device or won't upload to TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

We have integrated DeviceActivityReport into our Family Control app. All capabilities are added. We built the app and tested it, but when we wanted to upload it to TestFlight the following error happened

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f5UZ.png)

When we are adding NSExtensionMainStoryboard or NSExtensionPrincipalClass the following error appears during the installation process.

```
DeviceReport.appex with id com.example.example.DeviceReport defines either an NSExtensionMainStoryboard or NSExtensionPrincipalClass key, which is not allowed for the extension point com.apple.deviceactivityui.report-extension
```

How to resolve it?